# Debugging heavy single page application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-applications, crash

We're developing quite heavy single page application (SPA). However, it recently started to crash from time to time and it appears almost impossible to debug it. The traditional tools such us firebug or chrome's tools were also not very useful (perhaps they were not used correctly?).

Is there any tool that would allow me to view a crash log of a tab where I could find what caused a memory leak (or whatever the reason for the crash was)?

Thanks

Comment: If you're looking to debug why a chrome tab crashed, check out the following thread about reading chrome's debug logs:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896281/how-do-i-debug-a-tab-crash-in-google-chrome

Comment: You are probably going into a infinite recursive function. Have a look at the answers to this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815892/how-to-debug-javascript-when-it-goes-into-infinite-loops-and-recursive-calls-in

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [**Chromium**](http://www.chromium.org/Home) which is kind of browser especially for developers.

It has a batch of plugins for debugging and testing websites and SPA.

For example for memory leaking you can try to use [**LeakSanitizer**](http://www.chromium.org/developers/testing/leaksanitizer).