# Highstock crashing chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, highcharts

I have a graph that continuously crashes chrome. The crash doesn't even let dev tools load so I can't see if it's throwing a javascript error first. A similar graph works fine in chrome, the only difference being the one that crashes has a large span of null values. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas how I can begin to debug since dev tools doesn't work?

crashes chrome http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/DGS30/
does not crash chrome http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/series/DGS10/

Thanks!

Comment: How does look like your code of crashed example?

Comment: It seems to have fixed itself somehow. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

Similar bugs were reported here:

[here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=336403) and [there](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2608):

Both seems to use null values but states other problematic functions.  The bug report page states the bug has been resolved in >= 34.0.1799.0

Comment: I saw those, but I'm using Chrome 36.0.1985.125

Comment: You could try to use windbg as state in other post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10896281/how-do-i-debug-a-tab-crash-in-google-chrome

Comment: I'm on OSX. I tried starting Chrome from the command line and enabling logging with it being sent to stdout, but it didn't show anything.